# Efficient way to change color of Map Marker

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-mobile

I'm using a `GoogleMap` with lots of small markers loaded. We are talking perhaps 400-500 markers. Upon user interaction, I want to have a subset of those markers change color, perhaps 100-300 of them. I want to achieve this ideally in 30ms or under, but up to 50-60ms would be acceptable.

Right now I have code something like:

```
onUserInteraction... {
    changeColors(getTheSubset)
}

changeColors(subset) {
    getMarkersForSubset(subset).removeAllFromMap();
    map.addNewMarkers(subset)
}
```

So I remove the old markers in some color (say, green), and add new markers for those locations (say, black). When the subset is no longer relevant, I do the opposite process.

On the busiest parts of the map I am seeing this take 500ms or more, and there's noticeable lag with different markers changing colors at different times.  So I am curious if there is a better math-based way to draw small circles on a map and change their colors without removing/adding markers and while minimizing alloc/gc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `LevelListDrawable`s are not an option, due to Gmap's use of `BitmapDescriptorFactory`.

One solution I found was to draw a `Marker` on top of the old one with the new color, then delete the old one from underneath.

There were two issues to that.

- One, google-maps-android-v2 doesn't support z-indexing for `Marker`s.
- Two, if you have a lot of `Marker`s to change the color of, the performance of it causes artifacts.

Now, recently Google released an update that made `Marker`s with a common `Bitmap` a lot faster to draw, but you can always throw more `Markers` at it and break it.

I also attempted to draw a `Marker` on top, but with its visibility set to `false`, and to then set it to `true` when that location got "selected". This didn't seem too much faster although in fairness I did not benchmark it.

The conclusion: Don't change `Bitmap`s on `Marker`s. (For now)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `LevelListDrawable`s? Rather than removing and re-adding all of your markers when updating, you could have your various drawables with each color as the levels of a `LevelListDrawable`. Then you can call `setLevel()` to set the appropriate drawable with the color you want when you update your set of pins. I'm not 100% sure you can use a `LevelListDrawable` for the map pin, but it is worth a shot.

API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html

Example: http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2010/10/progress-bar-implementation-using-level.html

Comment: I tried it, but you can't set an icon level on MarkerOptions. And once you set `.icon` you can't call it again apparently.